# How to skip queue and make a job run first?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Say I have 10 jobs in a queue waiting for a resource, then I submit eleventh job which needs to be built before those 10 in the queue, what plugin can I use to achieve this? Looks like [accelerated-build-now-plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/accelerated-build-now-plugin/) will do the job, but I see it's not being maintained, any other suggestion please?

Comment: Did the response help you at all? If so, consider upvote and/or mark as answered. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

(Opinion based),
I it meets your needs, has no open issues that prevent your use case and has no vulnerability, then being up for adoption is not a roadblock, just a risk. After all, it's Open Source, so if there's an issue and can fix, just suit a PR and adopt it to fix.

Mind you, (at time of answering) it has a [number of open issues](https://plugins.jenkins.io/accelerated-build-now-plugin/#issues), low usage, no release in 8 years and importantly, may not work with new UI (LTS 2.277.1+).

You could look at [Simple Queue](https://plugins.jenkins.io/simple-queue/#documentation). Similar UI risk, low usage, be nice if it had a Changelog, but good README and active.